# How to solve dual boundary condition contradiction at the corner of an axially loaded cylinder?

Tags: symmetry, boundary-conditions, elasticity, continuum-mechanics, stress-strain

**Subject: Linear elasticity**

Consider an isotropic elastic cylinder rigidly bound to the surface on one end. The other end is under uniformly distributed static load (pressure for example).

[image]

I am trying to understand the boundary conditions at $r_{max}$ and $z_{max}$. It isn't very clear to me. In the following, I will write down how I understand the system. Please correct me where I'm wrong.

*External radial boundary condition*

At the external radial boundary, the stress vector is equal to zero. Mathematically, this can be written as:

$$ \vec P_n(r_{max}, \theta, z) = 
(\sigma _{rr}n_r + \sigma _{r \theta}n_{\theta} + \sigma _{rz}n_z)\vec r_0 + 
(\sigma _{r \theta}n_r + \sigma _{\theta \theta}n_{\theta} + \sigma _{\theta z}n_z)\vec \theta _0 +
(\sigma _{rz}n_r + \sigma _{\theta z}n_{\theta} + \sigma _{zz}n_z)\vec z_0 = 0 \tag 1$$

Also, the longitudinal and angular component of the unit normal vector of that surface is equal to zero, while the radial component is equal to one:

$$\vec n = (n_r, n_{\theta}, n_z) = (1, 0, 0) \tag 2$$

Since the problem is axially symmetric, all terms containing derivatives with respect to the angular coordinate are zero and the angular displacement is zero. Because the displacement terms of $\sigma _{\theta z}$ have these properties, $\sigma _{r \theta}$ is equal to zero. So now, the stress vector can be written as:

$$ \vec P_n(r_{max}, \theta, z) = \sigma _{rr} \vec r_0 + \sigma _{rz} \vec z_0 = 0 \tag 3$$

Here is an illustration of the vectors:

[image]

*External longitudinal boundary condition*

At the external longitudinal boundary, the stress vector is equal to a non-zero constant:

$$ \vec P_n(r, \theta, z_{max}) = 
(\sigma _{rr}n_r + \sigma _{r \theta}n_{\theta} + \sigma _{rz}n_z)\vec r_0 + 
(\sigma _{r \theta}n_r + \sigma _{\theta \theta}n_{\theta} + \sigma _{\theta z}n_z)\vec \theta _0 +
(\sigma _{rz}n_r + \sigma _{\theta z}n_{\theta} + \sigma _{zz}n_z)\vec z_0 = const \tag 4$$

In this case, the radial and angular component of the unit normal vector of that surface is equal to zero, while the longitudinal component is equal to one:

$$\vec n = (n_r, n_{\theta}, n_z) = (0, 0, 1) \tag 5$$

Similarly as before, $\sigma _{\theta z}$ is equal to zero. Now, the stress vector reduces to:

$$ \vec P_n(r, \theta, z_{max}) = \sigma _{rz} \vec r_0 + \sigma _{zz} \vec z_0 = const \tag 6$$

This is an illustration of the vectors:

[image]

*The intersection of the external radial and longitudinal boundary condition*

I do not know what happens at the corner boundary point at $(r_{max}, z_{max})$. Please help me understand. Here are my questions:

1. How is the unit normal vector defined at the corner of the cylinder? It seems to me like the corner has two normal unit vectors as I illustrated in the picture below, but I am pretty sure that is not possible.
2. How is the stress vector $\vec P_n (r_{max}, \theta, z_{max})$ defined at the corner of the cylinder? Which terms are zero and which are not?
3. How can I define the stress vector boundary condition at the corner of the cylinder? Is it even possible to define it in a way that is compatible with the physics of the system (meaning it satisfies both the external radial and longitudinal boundary conditions)?
4. Is there any literature on this problem?

[image]

Comment: You're. applying a combination of normal and shear loads on the ends?  The points at the corners contribute negligibly to the stress distribution.

Comment: I am applying pressure at the top of the cylinder, while the bottom of the cylinder is rigidly bound to the ground. The radial surface of the cylinder is free, meaning there is no stress applied to it. I need to know how to define the stress vector at that corner because it seems to affect my numerical solution in the form of a spike in the surface graph. This spike is physically impossible (I think).

Comment: Put a smallradius on the corner and see how it plays out.

Comment: That's what I was thinking. If there is no way to define this discontinuity using physics, I don't really have another option.

Comment: The force on the 2 ends is vertical and the state of stress is homogeneous, right?

Comment: I don't know the force on the lower end, I only know that there is no longitudinal and radial displacement at that end. At the top of the cylinder, the elementary forces are vertical, so the resultant sum of those elementary forces is vertical. The stress is uniformly distributed at the top of the cylinder if that is what you mean by homogeneous.

Comment: Why do you need to know the tracking stress at that exact point where the top meets the side?

Comment: As I said, I need to know how to define the stress vector at that corner because it seems to affect my numerical solution in the form of a spike in the surface graph. This spike is physically impossible (I think).

Comment: There is no spike because the point at the corner subtends zero area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Cauchy relationship between the stress tensor and the traction vector on a plane of arbitrary orientation (as characterized by the unit normal n) applies not only on the surface of your cylinder but on any surface specified in the interior of your cylinder. In the situation you describe, the three principal components of the stress tensor are aligned with the 3 coordinate directions z, r, and $\theta$, and are given by $\sigma_{zz}\neq 0$, and $\sigma_{rr}=\sigma_{\theta \theta}=0$. So on a plane oriented normal to the radial coordinate direction, the traction is 0, and on a plane oriented normal to the z coordinate direction (e.g., the upper and lower faces of the cylinder), the traction vector is normal to the surface and equal in magnitude to $\sigma_{zz}$.  This applied anywhere within the cylinder including right below the outer surfaces, or even in the vicinity of the corner location.